# data is not filled into textarea

Tags: jquery

I want to download a wiki-format preset into a textarea with jquery:

```
<form><textarea  name="wikitext" id="submittextarea"></textarea></form>
```

I use this script:

```
function download_to_textbox(url, el) {
        $.get(url, null, function (data) {
            // this is not reached, why???
            console.log("test")
            el.val(data);
        }, "text");
}
url='http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/mediawiki/api.php?action=parse&prop=wikitext&page=Template:Node';
download_to_textbox(url, $('textarea[name="wikitext"]'));
```

there is nothing in the textarea, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the data getting returned - have you logged the  data the ajax call returns to the console?

Comment: Is that a cross-domain request? Have you verified that the URL is being hit?

Comment: It is a same origin policy violation

Comment: firebug sais, the download via GET is "200 OK"

Comment: What does Firebug say the response *body* is?

Comment: Can you try a console.log(data) inside the function and confirm the correct response appears in chrome developer tools (console tab) or Firebug (again console tab).

Comment: I did and it doesent log "test". console logging outside of `$.get(url...` works

Comment: Cross-domain does not work. You can get it to work using JSONP in which you need a matching callback

You can get it to work by setting up a Proxy like mentioned already

Javascript only - not so sure if you will find a solution. Not likely

Comment: you are right, It was because of cross-site-scripting restrictions, I downloaded the site in the lolal folder and changed  `url = 'NodeVorlage.xml'` and now it all works fine. If you put that into an answer, I can mark that solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I would use a server side script (PHP) as a proxy to get contents to avoid the cross domain issues:

Call this proxy.php

```
$url='http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/mediawiki/api.php?action=parse&prop=wikitext&page=Template:Node';

$contents = file_get_contents($url);

echo $contents;
```

Call proxy.php from any AJAX call

You can make the request dynamic so you can reuse the proxy like so using $_POST[url] variable.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($_POST[url]);
echo $contents;
```

Comment: I need a javascript only solution in this case

Comment: JSONP would work but it needs a callback function and you need to have that defined on both sides. I think a proxy is your best bet

Comment: yep my dyslexia sorry

Comment: I don't have to load it from another domain, so I don't need neither PHP nor JSONP. but thanks ;)

Comment: Did you get this working rubo? I went to look for language encoding because I noticed you had German content but through that I see that you are calling a XML file (with html wrapper) but using dataType: 'text' whereas it should be html or xml depending on how you are unwrapping that xml block http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/mediawiki/api.php?action=parse&prop=wikitext&page=Template:Node

Comment: One more question Rubo - you are running on the domain http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/ with same subdomain? different subdomain will flag in browser as cross-domain error

Comment: related: [how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)