# How can I set 'X-Frame-Options' on an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, x-frame-options

If I create an `iframe` like this:

```
var dialog = $('<div id="' + dialogId + '" align="center"><iframe id="' + frameId + '" src="' + url + '" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="'+frameHeightForIe8+'" data-ssotoken="' + token + '"></iframe></div>').dialog({
```

How can I fix the following error with JavaScript?

> Refused to display `'https://www.google.com.ua/?gws_rd=ssl'` in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

You can't set `X-Frame-Options` on the `iframe`. That is a response header set by the domain from which you are requesting the resource (`google.com.ua` in your example). They have set the header to `SAMEORIGIN` in this case, which means that they have disallowed loading of the resource in an `iframe` outside of their domain. For more information see [The X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) on MDN.

A quick inspection of the headers (shown here in Chrome developer tools) reveals the `X-Frame-Options` value returned from the host.

[image]

Comment: With YouTube, you can change the endpoint URL to the "embed" version. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661182/embed-youtube-video-refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-opti  (I know this isn't strictly what the OP is searching for, but google gives this result first!)

Comment: Now 2021. According to the [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#syntax](latest MDN docs), DENY and SAMEORIGIN are the only remaining valid options, with ALLOW-FROM deemed obsolete. Does this mean that cross-site iframes are officially something of the past (except if explicitly circumvented with plugins, etc.)?

Comment: `Note: The Content-Security-Policy HTTP header has a frame-ancestors directive which obsoletes this header for supporting browsers.`

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Solution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

Answer (score 104):

`X-Frame-Options` is a header included in the *response* to the request to state if the domain requested will allow itself to be displayed within a frame. It has nothing to do with javascript or HTML, and cannot be changed by the originator of the request.

This website has set this header to disallow it to be displayed in an `iframe`. There is nothing that can be done in a client-side web browser to stop this behaviour.

[Further reading on X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: It's set in the response header, not request header. But otherwise accurate explanation!

Comment: @nickang that's what I meant, however I agree the terminology wasn't clear. I've edited it to remove any confusion. Thanks.

Comment: "There is nothing a client can do to stop this behaviour." - Thank you for clarifying this!

Comment: "There is nothing a client can do to stop this behavior." That's actually not true as my "client" could be a node server (or any other server) that downloads the content of the page (scraping) and makes the content (including CSS, JS, etc) available to be loaded in your own site

Comment: @Gregra you're correct. Unfortunately someone edited 'client' in to my answer to create that issue. I've updated the answer to remove that ambiguity.

Answer (score 46):

In case you are in control of the server that sends the content of the iframe, you can set the setting for `X-Frame-Options` in your web server.

#### Configuring Apache

To send the X-Frame-Options header for all pages, add this to your site's configuration:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

#### Configuring nginx

To configure nginx to send the X-Frame-Options header, add this either to your http, server or location configuration:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
```

#### No configuration

This header option is optional, so if the option is not set at all, you will give the option to configure this to the next instance (e.g., the visitors browser or a proxy)

Source: *[X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)*

Comment: This helped me. I comment out these two lines: `add_header   Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=86400; includeSubdomains";
add_header   X-Frame-Options DENY;` from the nginx-snippets, and then it worked straight away.

Comment: NGINX, **important to say where**, inside location?

Comment: May I know the location where I need to set this header for Apache?

Comment: For Apache add the options inside the <directive> tag for your website, most probably a config file inside /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

Answer (score 23):

Since the solution wasn't really mentioned for the server side:

One has to set things like this (example from [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server)). This isn't the best option as it allows in everything, but after you see your server working correctly, you can easily change the settings.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set X-Frame-Options "allow-from *"
```

Comment: where i need to add this lines ? in proxy ?

Comment: @YaaKouB I am not sure what you are trying to do but it can go into the .htaccess or the config files  for apache for example. FYI https://tecadmin.net/configure-x-frame-options-apache/

Comment: @MikeQ  have tried this but getting an issue  apache2.service failed because the control process exited

Comment: `allow-from` is deprecated you have to remove the header to "allow" embedding. `Header always unset X-Frame-Options`

Answer (score 7):

And if nothing helps and you still want to present that website in an iframe, consider using [X Frame Bypass Component](https://github.com/niutech/x-frame-bypass) which will use a proxy.

Answer (score 5):

Not really... I used:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true" >
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This looks like a solution, but is this a security breach?

Comment: It's **not** a good idea to disable same origin policy for your site unless you know exactly what you are doing. You should not allow domains different from yours to embed content. See https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-cors and similar tutorials.

Comment: Is it for [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)?

Answer (score 4):

The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>` or `<object>`. Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

For more information: *[X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)*

I have an alternate solution for this problem, which I am going to demonstrate by using PHP:

#### File *iframe.php*

```html
<iframe src="target_url.php" width="925" height="2400" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

#### File *target_url.php*

```php
<?php
  echo file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");
?>
```

Comment: Is this a viable solution to use the page after it loads? Will I be able to interact with the pages after inital load? Wouldn't every request for the domain have to be proxied in order to use the content after it loads?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to the website hosting the web page you want to serve within the `<iframe>` element, you can circumvent the `X-Frame-Options` SAMEORIGIN restrictions by using a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)-enabled reverse proxy that could request the web page(s) from the web server (upstream) and serve them to the end user.

Here's a visual diagram of the concept:

[image]

Since I was unhappy with the CORS proxies I found, I ended up creating one myself, which I called **CORSflare**: it has been designed to run in a [Cloudflare Worker](https://www.cloudflare.com/it-it/products/cloudflare-workers/) ([serverless computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serverless_computing)), and therefore it's a 100% free workaround, as long as you don't need it to accept more than 100.000 request per day.

You can find the proxy source code [on GitHub](https://github.com/Darkseal/CORSflare); the full documentation, including the installation instruction, can be found in [this post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/corsflare-free-cors-reverse-proxy-bypass-same-origin/) of my blog.

Comment: Is Server A requesting the content from Server B, or is the NOdeJS proxy doing that? For instance, is the request IP passed onto the Server B API?

Answer (score 2):

This is also a new browser security feature to prevent phishing and other security threats. For chrome, you can download an extension to prevent the browser from denying the request.
I encountered this issue while working on WordPress locally.

I use this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ignore-x-frame-headers/gleekbfjekiniecknbkamfmkohkpodhe

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you need to match the location in your Apache installation or any other service you are using.

If you are using Apache, then in the *httpd.conf* file:

```
<LocationMatch "/your_relative_path">
    ProxyPass absolute_path_of_your_application/your_relative_path
    ProxyPassReverse absolute_path_of_your_application/your_relative_path
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to install a browser plugin.

A web site which issues HTTP Header `X-Frame-Options` with a value of `DENY` (or `SAMEORIGIN` with a different server origin) cannot be integrated into an IFRAME... unless you change this behavior by installing a Browser plugin which ignores the `X-Frame-Options` Header (e.g. [Chrome's Ignore X-Frame Headers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ignore-x-frame-headers/gleekbfjekiniecknbkamfmkohkpodhe)).

Note that this not recommended at all for security reasons.

Comment: "solution" is a strong word, I'd say work around

Comment: We can not say every customer to install that plugin to see what's there in our iframe!

Answer (score 0):

The way around this is to grab the HTML server side, add a `<base href="..." />` so any relative and absolute paths still work.

Here's my node route
`/api/url/:url`

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const url = `https://${req.query.url}`;
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const urlContents = await response.text();

  // Prepend the base to make sure all relative and absolute paths work
  const urlContentsWithHead = `<base href='${url}' /></head>${urlContents}`;

  res.status(200).send(urlContentsWithHead);
}
```

You can then use this route directly in the iframe

```
<iframe src={`/api/url/${url}`} />
```

Oddly when I tried to do this "properly" by putting the `<base />` element just before the closing `</head>` tag by using a replace, it didn't work. But putting the base before all of the markup (even the `<html>`) seemed to work.

Not sure if there will be any adverse affects

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to an invalid value. In PHP

```
header("X-Frame-Options: ALLOWALL");
```

this will default to X-Frame-Options not set

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score -2):

You can set the x-frame-option in the web configuration of the site you want to load in iframe like this:

```xml
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Configuration of what? [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server)?

Comment: OK, probably not Apache. What is it then?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*

Comment: A guess would for [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Help me click that *delete* link.

Answer (score -2):

You can not really add the x-iframe in your HTML body as it has to be provided by the site owner and it lies within the server rules.

You can probably create a PHP file which loads the content of the target URL and iframe that php URL. This should work smoothly.

Comment: "You can probably" then post it as a comment if its not an answer

Comment: What if it turns out to be an answer MK

Comment: Then it is a suggestion that worked, not a specific solution, so it should be placed as a comment

Comment: It seems incomprehensible near *"that php URL"*. Can you [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55337170/edit)? But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Help me click that *delete* link.

Answer (score -3):

You can do it in the [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) instance level configuration file (*web.xml*).
You need to add the 'filter' and filter-mapping' in the *web.xml* config file.
This will add the [X-frame-options = DENY] to all the pages as it is a global setting.

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
        <param-value>DENY</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```