# Is it possible to block remote scripts from loading inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, node-webkit

I am creating iframes dynamically and I want to prevent scripts that don't originate from the iframes' origin. Is this even possible (via JavaScript/jQuery)? For example, if my page loads an iframe from `example.com` with the contents:

```
<script src="http://example.com/foo.js"></script>
<script src="http://something-else.com/bar.js"></script>
```

I want the `example.com` script to run, but I want the `something-else.com` script to be blocked and not run.

I am using [NW.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/tree/master) (formerly Node-Webkit), so I have full read-write access to the iframes' contents as if they were same-origin.

I've tried using plugins (like those that bring CORS in the picture, with whitelisting), but nothing I've tried is working.

An ideal solution would also allow me to whitelist specific other origins in addition to the iframe's origin.

EDIT:

Here is my browser project I am trying to implement this in: https://github.com/IdeasNeverCease/Aries

Here is the section of code the iframe loading is done in: https://github.com/IdeasNeverCease/Aries/blob/master/app.nw/resources/scripts/aries.js#L376-L687

Comment: Is the iframe in your domain? You would need to remove it on the server level.

Comment: @epascarello I'm using node-webkit (now NW.js). Because of this, I am able to load iframes as if they were on my domain. My browser project is here: https://github.com/IdeasNeverCease/Aries

Comment: I dont think that's possible, what do you mean by "as if they were on my domain"

Comment: @Melbourne2991 I said that because I didn't mention my browser project. I'm aware that if I had an iframe on my website that pointed to another page on my site, I could modify the contents of the iframe.

Comment: `content-security-policy`... set the http header `X-Frame-Options` with value `sameorigin`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh You can't set `X-Frame-Options` on iframes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27359031/1167646

Comment: You don't set that on some iframe... You send it with your HTTP-response to the browser. Now Browser will ensure that no-iFrame on your page can load content from some other source.

Comment: Sounds like you want the page in each iframe to have a `Content-Security-Policy` set to `script-src 'self';` (in order to prevent scripts from other origins from being loaded on the page). I'm not sure the best way to do this in node-webkit, but if you can inject a `<meta>` tag, you could do `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self';">` (For possibly more information, see this resolved bug report: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1672)

Comment: @apsillers I've been injecting custom code into iframes and I never thought about injecting a `<meta>` tag. Good grief. I'll test this when I get home later tonight.

Comment: @apsillers Can you post your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "scripts that don't originate from the iframes' source"? Do you mean you only want to load scripts from the same origin (e.g., an iframe from `example.com` can only load scripts from `example.com`) or d oyou want to disallow all script resources and only allow inline scripts (i.e., `<script>alert(1)</script>` is okay but `<script src="/foo.js">` is not okay)? I assumed you meant the first case in my answer, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @apsillers I meant the first case. I also want to whitelist sources from Twitter, Facebook, &c, to allow for usage of social share buttons. I am currently figuring that out now.

Comment: @NetOperatorWibby I edited these comment details back into the question; feel free to alter my edits however you see fit. By the way, you're in luck: CSP can also whitelist specific origins in addition to the current `self` origin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want to prevent scripts that don't originate from the iframes' source

This is exactly what a [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) (CSP) is for. A CSP can specify which origins are permitted for scripts, plugins, styles, media, etc. You need to cause each the iframe to have a CSP that prevents script loads outside of the current origin; this can be done with the simple policy `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';` (the `unsafe-inline` allows the iframe to have inline scripts and the `self` restricts loads to the same-origin resources only)

Traditionally, you need the server to send the `Content-Security-Policy` response header when serving the page. However, if you don't have control over the server-sent response headers (but *do* have control over the page content) you can imitate an HTTP response header with a `<meta>` tag like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

You can inject this programmatically (but read on for issues):

```
var m = document.createElement("meta");
m.httpEquiv = "content-security-policy";
m.content = "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';";
iframeElem.contentDocument.documentElement.appendChild(m);
```

However, this script-based injection might not work for you, because you'll only have a DOM to work with after the DOM is parsed from the HTML source. At that time, and the scripts from any (non-`async`) `<script>` elements will already have been fetched and run. You may need to manipulate the HTML directly, but I don't know enough about NW.js to tell you the best way to do that.

If you want to disallow *all* external script resources (even ones from the same origin), you can use `script-src 'none' 'unsafe-inline';`. To disallow *all* scripts, including loaded scripts and inline scripts, use `script-src 'none';`

In order to whitelist specific origins, simply add them as unquoted items in the CSP:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' *.twitter.com https://api.facebook.com
```

A leading `*.` allows all subdomains, and a leading `https://` limits the whitelist for that domain to secure `https://` addresses only.

Comment: Is there any similar mechanism that functions as a blacklist, rather than a whitelist? Use case is a stopping a bad actor on a well-known ad network from injecting code that calls a known URL. Whitelisting is infeasible because of the broad and changing set of valid URLs, vs. this one, known, bad URL.

Comment: @user359996 My guess is no: in general, what's to stop a bad actor from just rotating domains? Such a security measure seems to have limited usefulness. In your case, maybe there's customer-facing reasons why the bad ad company can't rotate domains, but a restriction like that for an attacker sounds like the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: For our purposes, blocking individual domains would actually be perfectly sufficient. They're not really a bad actor so much as just a very loosely coupled third-party doing something which, while not a security issue, nor even strictly illegitimate, is counter to the interests of our clients. If we did this, it is very unlikely they would notice or react, given the particulars of our own position in the market.