# Stop external .js from loading on WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, external, tableau-api

I have embedded an external data visualization into one of my WordPress pages. When I run Google's PageSpeed Insights, I get a warning that an unused external .js is using a LOT of resources (transfer size: 842kb, potential savings: 361kb). The js is "https://public.tableau.com/vizql/v_202022006180914/javascripts/vqlmobile.js").

Is it possible to target and block this resource from initiating on my website in a attempt to reduce resource load? Thank you in advance!

Site: https://maineoutcomes.com

Answer (score 2):

This code is likely being injected by a plugin that you're using.

**[You can programmatically prevent that script from being loaded](https://digwp.com/2019/03/disable-script-style-added-plugins/).**

The key steps are:

1. Find the `id` with which the offending script was loaded
2. Dequeue (probably in your custom theme package) the script with that `id`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  It's actually not triggered by a plugin.  Instead, it stems from embed code used to insert the data visualizations published on another site. The code I embedd into the body's div blocks references https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js - which I assume calls the .js above on mobile devices.  Using your referenced source above (and knowing I only have this .js call information: "https://public.tableau.com/vizql/v_202022006180914/javascripts/vqlmobile.js"), any insights on how to prevent loading the script?  I'm unfortunately not a javascript Jedi...

Comment: Ah. Well, if the piece of the embed code you can control involves an `iframe`, you might want to [look into this SO answer involving CSP for iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28366917/129086).