# How to delete something from a #document inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have an iframe which has another iframe inside of it. In the last iframe there is a #document inside which generates a whole web page as you can see in the picture.

[image]

I'm interested into deleting the  (it's marked with green).
Do you think it's possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Are both iframes on the same domain as your website? If not, you won't be able to manipulate anything inside them.

Comment: @Mr.Technician They are outside my domain...

Comment: You can delete them when they are in the same origin but even if you delete that it won't keep the script from executing - it's already running when you are able to access it.

Comment: As @n1md7 hinted at this isn't possible because the origin of the iframes differs from your site. :( your browser won't let you touch their contents.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300192/is-it-possible-to-block-remote-scripts-from-loading-inside-iframe