# Google maps - Not loading via <iframe>

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, iframe

In rails 4.2.4, I am trying to add the google maps feature via iframe but I am getting an error like

```
Refused to display 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIsfsdfsdjLr31nsdsdfsdf16LORmV4d89hhg&output=embed' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

View file is,

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIsfsdfsdjLr31nsdsdfsdf16LORmV4d89hhg&output=embed" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

How to solve this iframe issue?

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including the JavaScript file as an `iframe` instead of the actual embedded version of Google Maps. Your `src` value should look something like `https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Harrods,Brompton%20Rd,%20UK`. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/) the link to the Google Maps Embed API.