# Very simple <a href link not working

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm trying to link to a book on Amazon.  I've boiled it all down to a very simple piece of code which does not take me to Amazon when I click on the link.  If I just put the address into a browser then the page loads fine.  How can something so simple not work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/093849743X" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Amazon Link</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "A tryit editor piece of code"...?! What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry.  Poor use of English.  I just meant that I was trying the code in an online service where you can paste your code and 'try it'.

Comment: That's an important piece of contextual information you should clarify instead of remove.

Answer (score 3):

It's because most webpages don't allow you to display them in frames.
If you open the JS console of your browser you will see something like

```
Refused to display 'http://www.amazon.com/dp/093849743X/?tag=stackoverfl08-20' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Just save it as a .html file on your pc and run it. The link will work.

More information:
[How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

well it works fine on my pc if you want to show the link on your website you can use iframe in your code like

```
<iframe src="www.google.com" height="500" width="500"></iframe>
```