# jQuery iframe not able to set youtube url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, youtube

I am trying to do

Here is the code inside my HTML

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item"  id="placeYoutubeVideo"
        style="display:none" src="#" style="display:none" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In jQuery I am trying to change the src of the video

```
var neww = 'https://youtu.be/NOubzHCUt48';
        $('#placeYoutubeVideo').prop('src', neww)
```

But it is throwing the following error:

> Refused to display
>   'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOubzHCUt48&feature=youtu.be' in a
>   frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

How can I fix this?

If not possible is it possible to generate iframe with youtube url on click function?

help please.

Comment: This Possible duplicate: [How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe) might help you understand your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" id="placeYoutubeVideo" src="#" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () { 
var neww = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/NOubzHCUt48'; $('#placeYoutubeVideo').attr('src', neww); }); 
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vyt7gxwz/

> HTTP -> HTTPS = ERROR (X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN)
>
> HTTP -> HTTP = OK
>
> HTTPS -> HTTPS = OK
>
> HTTPS -> HTTP = ERROR (X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN)

Comment: Nothing is happening :(

Comment: http protocol, https security.

Comment: `<iframe class="embed-responsive-item"  id="placeYoutubeVideo"  src="#" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var neww = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/NOubzHCUt48';
$('#placeYoutubeVideo').attr('src', neww);
});
</script>` its work...

Comment: @DmitriyKlimov its working you should post this as answer

Comment: @DmitriyKlimov Its working.. wowwww Can you post this as answer, i have some clarification in your answer

Comment: is it possible to generate the iframe and then replace it with span inside the html ?

Comment: I mean i want to have this span <span id='putiframecontent'></span>

Comment: And then inside that i  want to put the iframe content inside that.. is that possible ?

Comment: Of course ! `$("#putiframecontent").html('<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" id="placeYoutubeVideo" src="#" allowfullscreen></iframe>');`  And then we start our code. Replace to `$('#putiframecontent > iframe')`

Comment: let me have a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can `replaceWith`

```
 var neww = 'https://youtu.be/NOubzHCUt48';
 var newContent = '<iframe class="embed-responsive-item"  id="placeYoutubeVideo" style="display:none" src="'+neww +'" style="display:none"  allowfullscreen></iframe>'

// Replace 'neww ' with your new URL

     $('#placeYoutubeVideo').replaceWith(newContent );
```

Comment: Thanks, but am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).replace is not a function

Comment: Same error now 'Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOubzHCUt48&feature=youtu.be' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var neww = 'https://youtu.be/NOubzHCUt48';
iframe.setAttribute("src", neww);
```

---

**Syntax**

```
element.setAttribute(attributename,attributevalue)
```

**Parameter Values**

```
attributename   |  String   |  Required. The name of the attribute you want to add
attributevalue  |  String   |  Required. The value of the attribute you want to add
```

[HTML DOM `setAttribute()` Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

---

**EDIT 01**

If you want add that to only one element

```
document.getElementsByID("placeYoutubeVideo").setAttribute("src", neww);
```

Comment: should i replace src with placeYoutubeVideo ?

Comment: or how can i tell that it should be displayed in the div placeYoutubeVideo

Comment: remove src and in `<iframe>`

Comment: is there only one video ?? or

Comment: Only one video was there

Comment: Check **Edit 01** as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99120/discussion-between-biz-dev-b-and-abdulla).

Answer (score 0):

`X-Frame-Options: Sameorigin` is used by YouTube to prevent [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking).  You will need to embed the actual playlist.

[Embed videos & playlists](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en)