# Getting dynamic PHP links and iframe to work?

Tags: php, html, iframe, video-embedding

I'm creating a wordpress theme and am having trouble generating a video link to go into an iframe source. I've tried troubleshooting and it seems that the issue is beyond wordpress and I can't actually input any link with PHP to work with iframe. Here's an example for simplicity's sake.

```
<iframe src="<?php echo 'https://vimeo.com/159120552'; ?>" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The PHP works as far as I can tell (when I inspect it, the link is in the correct place), but there appears to be a blank web document created in the iframe instead.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known issue of iframe and PHP?

Comment: no need to PHP `echo` the link here, just use as `<iframe src="https://vimeo.com/159120552"  ..........>`

Comment: Presumably the question just uses a hardcoded link as an example and OP actually wants to put a dynamic link in there later.

Comment: Right, the link isn't hardcoded normally and will be generated dynamically using extra metadata on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue not related to PHP . Its throwing an error **refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.**
Please refer [How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)

Comment: Right you are! This particular issue is with my own vimeo link, as I was using the web link and not the embed link. (vimeo.com/##### as opposed to player.vimeo.com/video/#######)