# Polymer Designer and <iframe>

Tags: iframe, browser, polymer

I'm trying to put in an iframe in Polymer Designer (https://polymer-designer.appspot.com/) but it won't display any webpage with "http" and other websites like "google" and "youtube" I don't know if there is any way I can fix this but if any of you have an idea how to fix it I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert an `<iframe>` into an element from within the Polymer Designer:

1. Open the Polymer Designer with **http** (http://polymer-designer.appspot.com/) (to load the `<iframe>` in step 3).
2. Click **<>** at the top left to go into Code View.
3. Inside the `<template>` tag, add your `<iframe>`. It should look like this:

   ```
   <polymer-element name="my-element">
     ...
     <template>
       <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/"></iframe>
     </template>
   </polymer-element>
   ```

Notes:

- The Polymer Designer has not been updated in a while, and it's using an obsolete Polymer version with elements that are no longer relevant. I recommend following the [Polymer docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/) to get started with the newest version of Polymer (1.4.0).
- If you open your browser console while in Polymer Designer, you'll see error messages when you try to use an `<iframe>` to `google.com` or `youtube.com`:

  > Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
  >
  > Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

  This error indicates that the servers disallow loading of the resource in an `<iframe>` outside of their domain (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27359031/6277151) for more details).
- The browser console log will also show you the error regarding **http**:

  > Mixed Content: The page at 'https://polymer-designer.appspot.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.w3schools.com/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

  To resolve this, you can change the `<iframe>` URL to use **https** (if that server allows) to match the current protocol, or simply access the Designer from **http** (http://polymer-designer.appspot.com/).