# Can't link to iframe from DDmenu

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a CSS banner/menu. The links (buttons) should target to an iframe on the same page. It's not working. Nothing appears in the iframe but the SRC page. Clicking on the link return a blank within the iframe.

Have a look: http://ihrc.site88.net/iframe.html (click on link called target iframe main also have a look at the source)

Comment: Hi Worldly, welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and improve your question according to those guidelines as it is currently very unclear what you're intending to achieve here and how you're going about it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly when you click on the button you want the iframe src to be changed. But when you click the **target iframe main** button the iframe becomes blank but if you check the console it gives you "Refused to display '*https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=H1wbWOmhAavT8geWn6eYDg' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'*."

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PiO9.jpg)

Which, if i undestand correctly, is caused as the target url is on a different domain i.e google.com. I would suggest upload another page on the same domain & check.

But if you still want to display a webpage from a different domain then [How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe) may help.

Incase it is something else then a little more elaboration is required.