# Cross subdomains iframe access

Tags: html, apache2, subdomain

Is there any way to open different subdomain site in the iframe?

Ex.
I'm on a.xyz.com and here is iframe pointing to b.xyz.com.

> a.xyz.com

```
<body>
    <iframe src="http://b.xyz.com"></iframe>
</body>
```

> b.xyz.com

```
<body>
    B subdomain iframe
</body>
```

As for now I'm getting cross-origin error.

Load denied by X-Frame-Options: b.xyz.com does not permit cross-origin framing.

Comment: That isn't the default behaviour. You need to provide a [mcve] and **precisely quote** the  error message.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe

Comment: It's not the case to disable SAMEORIGIN at all. The site would be vurneable to clickjacking

Comment: You've banned all other origins from loading the page but you want another origin to access it. You can't have it both ways. Maybe you should look at what the allowed values for X-Frame-Options are.