# How do you ask for input in html, and if you can is there anyway to concatenate it in src?

Tags: html, iframe

fellow programmers!!! I know this sounds really dumb, but I'm currently trying to embed an iframe in a website. I want the website to ask the user for a website... then when that happens it activates the iframe code. here is my idea for code to give you a better idea...

```
<iframe src = "http://" + input></iframe>
```

obviously this doesn't work, even I know that... but what would make this work? or if it doesn't work, is there any way to unblock a website from a school chromebook, or could I write a program that could do that. :) This probably won't get answered because it's extremely stupid, but I'd love any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<HTML>
<iframe id="urlframe" src=""></iframe>
<script>
function askforsite() {
var url = prompt("Enter site URL: ");
document.getElementById("urlframe").setAttribute("arc", "http://"+url);
}
</script>
<body onLoad="askforsite();"></body></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar, but with a form so you can reuse it:

```
<input type="text" id="url">
<button onclick="showURL()">Show Website</button>
<iframe id="newPage" src = ""></iframe>
<script>
  function showURL() {
    var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
    document.getElementById('newPage').src = url;
  }
</script>
```

You may have some issues with "[Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)" from some sites though.

Comment: Okay. Yea. I'm pretty new to html, I know a lot, but I didn't know script was a thing. Actually me and a buddy of mine were trying something to create a program to grab the most popular projects from a site, and we failed terribly. But, it was fun because he didn't know hardly any java, and I knew what it all meant, I'd just never seen it before.

Comment: I'll see if this works and tell you if it works. I think it will though.

Comment: OMG It works. Thanks :D Check it out - http://wchsunblocked.weebly.com/unblocked-pages.html.