# Url is not loading in iFrame Blank Screen

Tags: html, css, iframe

```
<iframe src="http://bhasuri.ateesdemo.com/" height="600">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

this url is not loading in my iframe tag,

Comment: Perhaps a `width` would be helpful here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is so because:

> Refused to display 'http://bhasuri.ateesdemo.com/' in a frame because
>   it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

[image]
`X-Frame-Options` `SAMEORIGIN` is a response header set by the domain from which you are requesting the resource (http://bhasuri.ateesdemo.com in your example). They have set the header to SAMEORIGIN in this case, which means that they have disallowed loading of the resource in an iframe outside of their domain.

For more info refer : [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Answer (score 1):

This is the error I'm getting: 
"Refused to display 'http://bhasuri.ateesdemo.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'"

Which means that the owner of the page set its server to only allow "sameorigin" URLs to be allowed to present the page.

[How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)