# Why are these icon links unclickable?

Tags: html, css

I have some social media links on my website with an icon inside the anchor tags. While hovering over the links produces the hand pointer, the links themselves seem unclickable. The only way to open them is to select open in a new tab, which isn't what I want.

I've included the basic JS fiddle below so you can get a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

I haven't included the font for the icons themselves in the js fiddle but it shouldn't be required to get the gist of what's going on.

https://jsfiddle.net/bxantc4j/

```
<div id="searchandsocial">
    <ul class="social-network social-circle">                      
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Money-Saving-Answers-488686301254180/" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/moneysavingqa" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.social-network {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-left:0 !important;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.social-network li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 5px;
}


/* footer social icons */
.social-network a.icoRss:hover {
    background-color: #F56505;
}
.social-network a.icoFacebook:hover {
    background-color:#3B5998;
}
.social-network a.icoTwitter:hover {
    background-color:#33ccff;
}
.social-network a.icoGoogle:hover {
    background-color:#BD3518;
}
.social-network a.icoVimeo:hover {
    background-color:#0590B8;
}
.social-network a.icoLinkedin:hover {
    background-color:#007bb7;
}
.social-network a.icoRss:hover i, .social-network a.icoFacebook:hover i, .social-network a.icoTwitter:hover i,
.social-network a.icoGoogle:hover i, .social-network a.icoVimeo:hover i, .social-network a.icoLinkedin:hover i {
    color:#fff;
}
a.socialIcon:hover, .socialHoverClass {
    color:#44BCDD;
}

.social-circle li a {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    border-radius:50%;
    text-align:center;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    font-size:16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.social-circle li i {
    margin:0;
    line-height:34px;
    text-align: center;
}

.social-circle li a:hover i, .triggeredHover {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms--transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.social-circle i {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s;
    transition: all 0.8s;
}

.social-circle a {
 background-color: #717171;
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to close the div tag? Is that causing the error?

Comment: I suppose it connects with iframe restrictions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe

Comment: There is no iframe. I have the exact same code on my website, and while the pointer changes, clicking doesn't seem to go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use target="_top" in your a tags.. It will work..

```
 <div id="searchandsocial">
        <ul class="social-network social-circle">                      
            <li><a target="_top" href="https://www.facebook.com/Money-Saving-Answers-488686301254180/" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a target="_top" href="https://twitter.com/moneysavingqa" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to make any difference. Clicking the icons doesn't do anything only opening in a new tab will work. Tried in both Safari and Firefox. I don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The link is not unclickable, It actually works, but the page you're linking to somehow does not display  within your page. Try a different http://www.xx.xx and you'll see.

I Guess FB does not like to run in an fiddler iframe

Comment: When I click on the links nothing happens at all. Regardless of where they links to. The only way I can open them is to right click and select

Comment: Please change the url of the link to an 'iframe friendly' url like 'https://jsfiddle.net' and you'll see left click works.

Comment: I've tested this several times in your jsfiddle in **Chrome. IE and Firefox**. 
Sometimes it loads slowly but every time it works. Just Try and you'll see!
If it does not work on your site please send the site-url or code (css+html+js)

Comment: @C-M I guess you did not try my aolution. So, just to prove my case i've set up am colab at https://jsfiddle.net/bxantc4j/#&togetherjs=H9sgsTqPrC
Other url Works!

Comment: The page linked to makes no difference. Changed one of the links to the BBC. Still cannot click on it and open a page.

Comment: @C-M I think you've got other problems if my fiddler does not work on your system but does work for me. What kind of browser(s) do you use and/or what website (outside of ffiddler) can I test?

Comment: Safari, Firefox, Opera, and Chromium. Can't click the links on any of them. The code is employed on https://moneysavinganswers.com

Comment: url of employement?

Comment: Click on them, nothing happens at all. Now if you right click and select open new tab, then they work. Bizarre. They are just normal links, so I don't quite understand it.