# yammer authentication using JS SDK in ionic 2/cordova

Tags: cordova, oauth-2.0, ionic2, yammer

I need to authenticate a user using Yammer before posting comments from my ionic 2 app. i am using yammer js sdk for this. its working in browser fine. its opening login popup and closing. when i try running the same in mobile its opening the inappbrowser and showing about:blank at the bottom. not redirecting from there.

i am calling the sdk this way:

```
yam.platform.login((loginResp)=>{

  console.log("loginResp:"+JSON.stringify(loginResp));
});
```

i have included the js sdk this way:

```
<script data-app-id="appid" src="external/yammer_js_sdk.js"></script>
```

because of the above login call its opening the inappbrowser but stuck there.
can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you notice in Browser, login opens as a pop up window. Which is not possible in Ionic/Cordova app. Check the logs by connecting the simulator/device and you would notice

"{adfs redirection URL} in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'."

Check another post from StackOverFlow which talks about the error @ [How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)

Try using User Impersonation i.e, Pre-Auth @ [Microsoft Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askyammer/2016/11/04/preauthorizing-the-yammer-js-sdk/)
Which talks about 
1. Generating Verified Admin Developer Token for Yammer
2. Fetch UserID using Email ID.
3. Fetch User Access Token using Impersonation.
4. Set AuthToken using yam.platform.setAuthToken({token}) - This avoid per user login.

Weigh your requirements and you may use this approach.