# How to use iframe in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using below code to display iframe

```
<iframe src="www.w3schools.com" width="100%">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

But it is not working and showing result like.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ywKS.png]

and when I check console and found

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY8zL.png]

Comment: Add `http://` ou `https://` to load the iframe.

Comment: Thanks for Answering but still having the another issue like I found in console that Refuse to display 'https://www.w3school.com/' in a frame because (index):1 it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SameOrigin'

Comment: the file doesn't exist on the location that you havegiven

Comment: <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="100%">
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe> I am using this code, now let me know what's the cause ?

Comment: iframes are a HTML tag and not php or codeigniter related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="100%">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

That's what you see in console when you inspect the page.

`Refused to display 'https://www.w3schools.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

You cannot use all the sites to be shown within the iframe on your site. Here is a good read on this issue.

[How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo site_url('www.w3schools.com');?>"> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are accessing `w3schools.com`, this causes the browser to 'think' which is a file, not a complete url.

The correct one is `https://www.example.com` or `http://www.example.com`

Before adding a site to an iframe, you should check the headers that the site brings in the response. At the `w3schools.com` site, the server reports the `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN` header.

This header informs whether or not the site can be added to an iframe, frame, or object. When the header value is `SAMEORIGIN`, only the `w3schools.com` site can add its pages to the iframe.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options