# onClick inside an in div loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

I load a page inside a div. This div supposed to trigger a function on a mouse click. I would like that this onClick event also works when you click on the loaded page.

If you load a page inside the div, the functions of the loaded page only works for that page.
How can I make it happen that also the onClick function get triggered for the loaded page?

This is a simple example of the code:

```js
function load() {
  var url_view = '<object type="text/html" data="http://www.example.com/"></object>';
  document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=url_view;
}
window.onload = load;
  function showbox() {
    alert("test");
  }
```

```html
<div id ="frame"  onclick="showbox()">
  <div id="image">
  </div>
  <div class="infotext">
    <span>here comes some text.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**To be clear**
What I want to achieve is that when you load the page, you'll load data from example.com in a div with the id "image". This event happens with the function 'load()', on window.load.

When that is ready, I would like that you trigger the 'showbox()' function on a mouseclick when you click **inside** the div with the id "image" (the div where example.com is loaded into).

Comment: @UdhayTitus with `body onload` you load the external page into the div on the page load, but it doesn't make that the onclick function gets triggered when you click inside the div with the loaded page

Comment: can you explain your question little more

Comment: @UdhayTitus What I want to achieve is to trigger the onclick function as well when you click on the loaded content. This doesn't work right now. If you click on the div where the "http://www.example.com/" data is loaded into, the function doesn't get triggered

Comment: If you just want to use the content in the loaded `#image` for viewing purposes only, you can add the following to your css: `object { pointer-events: none; }`

Comment: @Patrick2607 I would like to still have the possibility to scroll

Comment: Can't you add your different page into HTML instead of calling it from JavaScript?

Comment: @TheUnKnown you mean copy/paste the HTML code of the page between the div with the id "image"?

Comment: Have you tried the event delegation approach. jQuery can provide it easily like

`jQuery(document).on('click','#frame',function(e){ showbox()})` the ID `#frame` should be unique.

Comment: @techie_28 can you give an example how to implement this? I'm trying it, but I cannot get it working.

Comment: Place this `jQuery(function(){jQuery(document).on('click','#iframe',function(e){showbox()})});` after the `showbox` function definition. Press F12(for developer tools of browser) & click on the image or wherever you need & see if `console` shows anything?

Comment: @techie_28 when I implement it, it does work on the data within the div with id "frame", but not the part where the webpage is loaded (the div with id "image")

Comment: Do you mean it should also work if div with id 'image' is clicked? does it work when `infotext` div is clicked?

Comment: @techie_28 exactly! Yes, it does work when the `infotext` div is clicked.

Comment: That is perhaps due to your usage of `object` tag could you instead use any other relevant HTML element like `img` or just insert all the contents into `image` div itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197379/discussion-between-koen-de-haan-and-techie-28).

Comment: @KoendeHaan No, I meant the link that you're passing in the `<object>` in the Javascript, you should paste that in HTML, so after that you can create onclick event for the entire page when it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<div id ="frame">
  <div id="image">
  </div>
  <div class="infotext">
    <span>here comes some text.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function showbox() {
  alert("show box");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $.get('https://jsfiddle.net/about', function(data) {
    $('#image').html(data);
    showbox();
  });

  $('#image').click(function() {
    showbox();
  });
});
```

Run it on jsfiddle due to CORS: https://jsfiddle.net/usn9qam7/1/

Comment: With this you trigger the function one time, after the external page is loaded into the div. Unfortunately it doesn't make that the onclick function works when you click inside the div with the loaded page, and that is what I would like to achieve.

Comment: @KoendeHaan I have updated my answer, could you check please?

Comment: I'm always against implicitly doing `$el.click()` because such can cause many weird behaviors when an application grows in complexity. Sometimes you don't need to execute every single possible bound Event-name on an element, rather just call `showbox()` function. And `showbox()` speaks more than a `$el.click()`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you are right! I have updated my answer.

Comment: @RenanAraújo what I mean is that when you load the page, you'll load data from example.com in a div with the id "image". This event happens with the function 'load()', on window.load. When that is ready, I would like that you trigger the 'showbox()' function on a mouseclick when you click **inside** the div with the id "image" (the div where example.com is loaded into).

Comment: @KoendeHaan I'm not seeing any problem related to js events. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/usn9qam7/ Probably you are having problem with CORS, but this is not related to js events. Check you browser errors to verify that.

Comment: @RenanAraújo I indeed had problems with CORS, excuse me. Anyway, if I do it like that, I loose the working of the javascript on the other page, so I would like to use the `object` tag.

Comment: @KoendeHaan Using object tag you will need to handle with X-Frame-Options. I wasn't able to create a fiddle with that. To know more about it, you can check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/27358966/5071902