# Why the Tag ***iframe*** did not work when the URL was finished by .com?

Tags: html

Why the Tag ***iframe*** did not work when the URL was finished by .com?

```html
<iframe name="W3" src="https://www.codecademy.com"></iframe>
```

This tag did not work becouse it was finishing URL (.com)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with this stackoverflow question: [How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)

For example if we change the url to https://jquery.com, the iframe works.

```html
<iframe name="jquery" src="https://jquery.com"></iframe>
```

Therefore, I dont think you can use the site you're trying to use in an iframe.