# Dynamics, iFrames

Tags: javascript, c#, html, microsoft-dynamics

Good day everyone.

So I have a website and I am trying to embed in an iframe a dynamics server and it keeps throwing an error something about

'Refused to display `https://XXXXXXXXXXXX` in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Any ideas how I can get it to work?

This happens when we try to redirect the page to a login page.

Thanks

Comment: You can't get this "work", if you can't control  `https ://XXXXXXXXXXXX`. The error message tells you, that the server refuses to show this content in an iframe. (The content is actually loaded, but browsers won't show it due to the `X-Frame-Options` header.)

Comment: Maybe this helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Check [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) hearder:

> The **`X-Frame-Options`** HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>`. Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

Based on the above statement, this is something that the 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXX' has added to the page to disallow it from being used as an `<iframe>`

You can see that this can even be configured globally on a web server level, to secure all the websites.

If the website is in the same domain the workaround is easier using `SameOrigin` value.

If you want to allow all, then just don't set the response header for the XXXXXXXX site at all (if you have access to it).

Comment: Thank you for than. The login server is not on the same domain - maybe thats why. I will try and see if the host can change the settings for us.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept useful answers! Cheers!