# Unable to embed stackoverflow web in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to embed `Stack OverFlow` website into a html page using `iFrame`, but I am unable to do that. I have tried to embed my other two websites and those are displaying correctly and this one is not getting displayed in my page.

The `iFrame` i used in the code:

```
 <iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></iframe>
```

And the error is

```
 Refused to display 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

Please tell me is there any method to access the `Stack OverFlow`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There isn't.  If you could get around `X-Frame-Options`, there would be no point having it in the first place

Comment: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

The [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>`. Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

The added security is only provided if the user accessing the document is using a browser supporting X-Frame-Options.