# Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: reactjs

When i'm trying to open my website in iframe.but it showing this.
i used reactjs for this project.

[error on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/984qk.png)

trying to open my website in iframe but it throwing error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)

Comment: no this one is different @Konrad

Comment: I don't see any question in your post

Comment: I got my solution. I need to whitelist domain from server end.